# How to break a grep regex search pattern

Tags: command-line, grep

I'm using a grep regex search in a bash script, that does contain quite a lot of search terms.

```
some commands \
 | grep -E 'search1|search2|search3|search4|search5|search6|search7|search8|search9|search10'
```

is it possible to break this command to make it more readable?

so it would look somehow like this:

```
some commands \
 | grep -E 'search1|search2|search3|search4|search5|\
            search6|search7|search8|search9|search10'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to option `-e`

```
some commands \
 | grep -E -e 'search1|search2|search3|search4|search5' \
           -e 'search6|search7|search8|search9|search10' \
           -e ...\
           -e ...
```

Comment: Big thumbs up for a great answer, and an educational one.

Answer (score 2):

If a pattern is divided into lines, grep treats each line as a separate and independent pattern. Thus one solution is:

```
command | grep -E 'search1|search2|search3|search4|search5
search6|search7|search8|search9|search10'
```

There is no `|` at the end of the first line or else it will be interpreted as or emptyspace and grep thinks that emptyspace matches everything.  Also do not put a space at the beginning of the continuation line or else the space is included in the pattern.

Comment: I didn't believe it at first, thinking that the 'CR' (return/enter) at the end of `search5` would be counted as part of the regex match. It's not, to my surprise. I've added the proof example to the solution.